# Copy from one location to another

Tags: shell

```
export SQLFILENAME=$1

scp -prv scratch/patchtestnew/db_new_temp/*/$SQLFILENAME /scratch/patchtestnew/db_new/*/
```

Want to copy from one location to another but don't know the intermediate directories and hence placed * but it doesn't catch the location

There is only one directory inside db_new and  db_new_temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work, provided that you can guarantee there's only one directory in `db_new` and no files. Also you should quote both the `$1` and `$SQLFILENAME` in case they contain uncommon characters. (and you don't need `scp` if you're copying on the same host)

Otherwise, it's supposed to "just work". If it doesn't, try listing both locations with `ls` - that should give you an idea about what's going wrong.

If you can't guarantee that there's never going to be another file/directory under `db_new`, I'd recommend finding another way to solve the problem though. You can not only get silent failures, but also silent data loss this way.